# How to make PanoramaItem use all the screen width on Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone, panorama-control

I need my app to open on a first PanoramaItem that occupy the full screen width, without showing part of the next PanamoraItem.

On the Facebook app we have exactly what I need: the first page open uses all the screen but if the user selects the button on the left top corner OR if he swipes to the right, then in both case the menu of options is open occupying only part of the screen so the user sees that he can swipe to the left to go back to the main page (his timeline) in 'fullscreen'. On the right side of the main page the same thing happens if he swipes to the left or if he presses the Chat option, opening a list of friends on the right side and not occupying all the screen width available.

Anyone knows a sample that does the same, or could suggest me a control or something that could lead me to the expected result? Maybe if someone at least suggest me how I could use the full width of the screen in one specific PanoramaItem I could manage to get to what I need.

Thanks =)

Comment: Have a look at the Pivot control: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff941098(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Pivot control always occupy the full width of the screen. I need it to happen only on the main PanoramaItem and for the others I need them to show a glimpse of the next or past PanoramaItem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I just found the project [SettingsPageAnimation](http://depblog.weblogs.us/2013/07/30/facebook-like-settings-pane-with-gestures-windows-phone/) which does exactly what I want at least with the left menu. The linked page includes a video showing how it works ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Pivot control ? In which pivot item will occupy full width of the screen, also there is a heading in top to navigate.

For deatil :
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff941098(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff941098%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Pivot control always occupy the full width of the screen. I need it to happen only on the main PanoramaItem and for the others I need them to show a glimpse of the next or past PanoramaItem